# Получение информации массива объектом циклом each

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть обьект:

```
data = {
    badges: [
        0: {
            img:"/assets/img/badges/024-medal-31.png",
            title:"Rank 1"
        }
    ],
    email: "usermail@mail.com",
    id: "12345678",
    joinDate: timestamp,
    name: "User Name",
}
```

В массиве `badges` может быть сколько угодно обьектов той же структуры. Почему следующий код вовсе ничего не делает?

```
$.each(data.badges, function() {
    console.log(this.img);
});
```

`each` полностью игнорируется, не подскажете почему и как достать информацию каждого обьекта в `badges`?

JSON.stringify(data):

> {"badges":[],"email":"usermail@mail.com","joinDate":"timestamp","name":"User
>   Name","id":"12345678"}

---

Обьект `data` создан ранее примерно следующим образом:

```js
let userBadges = [];
userInfo.badges.forEach(doc => {
    doc.badgeRef.get()
    .then(res => { userBadges.push( res.data() ) }) //data() = обьект {img: , title:}
});
data.badges = userBadges;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не "игнорируется", а до него не доходит из-за синтаксической ошибки. Ненужная `0:`.

```js
var data = {
  badges: [
    {
      img: "/assets/img/badges/024-medal-31.png",
      title: "Rank 1"
    }
  ],
  email: "usermail@mail.com",
  id: "12345678",
  joinDate: '',
  name: "User Name",
}

$.each(data.badges, function() {
  console.log(this.img);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*Update*

Вы пытаетесь вывести данные, не дожидаясь завершения асинхронных функций, что подтверждается наблюдаемым `"badges":[]`.

Comment: Не в этом проблема, массив был создан ранее и выглядит именно так. Я взял его с консоли потому он оформлен криво... Я добавлю информацию в вопрос если скажете что добавить.

Comment: @Telion Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код".

Comment: Я к тому что я не могу изменить сам обьект, он такой какой есть ибо создан автоматически, а вы в своем вопросе изменили именно обьект. Мне нужно изменить вывод обьекта так что бы с тем самым нулем он выводился правильно, я добавлю примерный код создания обьекта в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил, вот код выше создает именно структуру которую я показал.

Comment: @Telion Выведите `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` и скопируйте в вопрос.

Comment: @Telion Хотя, можно этого не делать. Я уже обо всем догадался. Вы пытаетесь вывести данные, не дожидаясь завершения асинхронных функций.

Comment: Боги, точно. А я уже минут 40 ломаю голову что ж я не так далею и более того почему нет ошибок. Спасибо! =)